# Convert repeating and non repeating rows of data to headers in python while keeping the data with its corresponding header

Tags: python, pandas, csv, pivot

I am trying to write a python script to transform some csv data. Didn't get too far using groupby or multiindex. I want to go from this:

```
cat, animal
A, 5000
B, 6000
C, 8000
D, 6000
A, 3000
B, 2000
C, 6000
D, 1000
A, 4000
B, 1000
C, 1000
D, 3000
blue, color
```

To this:

```
cat        A      B      C      D      blue
animal    5000   6000   8000   6000   color
animal    3000   2000   6000   1000   color
animal    4000   1000   1000   3000   color
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a custom [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot.html)/[`pivot_table`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html):

```
out = (
 pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None, names=['col', 'val'])
   .assign(index=lambda d: d.groupby('col').cumcount())
   .pivot_table(index='index', columns='col', values='val',
                sort=False, aggfunc='first')
   .ffill().rename_axis(index=None, columns=None)
)
```

Output:

```
       cat      A      B      C      D    blue
0   animal   5000   6000   8000   6000   color
1   animal   3000   2000   6000   1000   color
2   animal   4000   1000   1000   3000   color
```